# Perl - Capture and Substitute Multiple Matches in an If Statement

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, regex-group

I've been building a script to take some output from IBM's SPSS Statistics package and turn it into SPSS input syntax. I'm currently having the following problem that I can't seem to figure out. I've got some text that looks like the following:

```
VALUE LABELS V10
-1
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
-50.00
-33.33
 -10 "Don't Know".
```

I want to replace the negative values that aren't followed by labels in quotations and that don't have a space indentation with a label that says ' -9 "Missing"', and then I want to capture each of these negative values in a hash along with the variable name (i.e., V10, V11) so that I can print them in a recode statement later on. I'm reading this file through perl, splitting the "lines" by the literal period followed by a new line (which signifies the end of a command in SPSS). However, the code I've come up with so far is only replacing and capturing one negative value match per "line", and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My current code looks like this:

```
my %negmiss;
my @lines = split(/(\.\n)/,$_);
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my $modline = $line;
    if ($line =~ /VALUE LABELS\s(\S+)/g) {
       my $label_name = $1;
       if ($line =~ /\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)\n/g) {
           $modline =~ /\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)\n/\n -9 \"Missing\"\n/g;
           push my @negname, $label_name;
           push @{$negmiss{$label_name}}, $1;
       }
    }
print $modline;
}
foreach (@negname) {
    print "RECODE $_ (@{ $negmiss{$_} } = -9\.\n";
}
```

It partially works, but again, it's only substituting and capturing one negative value per each of the "lines", so my output looks like this:

```
VALUE LABELS V10
 -9 "Missing"
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
 -9 "Missing"
-33.33
 -10 "Don't Know".

RECODE V10 (-1 = -9).
RECODE V11 (-50.00 = -9).
```

How can I capture and replace both the -50.00 and the -33.33 for the V11 "line"?

Edit: I want my output to look like this:

```
VALUE LABELS V10
 -9 "Missing"
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
 -9 "Missing"
 -9 "Missing"
 -10 "Don't Know".

RECODE V10 (-1 = -9).
RECODE V11 (-50.00 = -9).
RECODE V11 (-33.33 = -9).
```

Comment: What _should_ your output look like, given that input?

Comment: Post edited to show what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your problem is here:

```
/\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)\n/\n -9 \"Missing\"\n/g;
```

Because you prefix *and* suffix your pattern with `\n` it means your *second* "\n" is consumed by the previous match - so it won't match twice.

Change that to

```
/\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\n)/\n -9 \"Missing\"\n/g;
```

(or probably better just `$`) and it should be ok.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '';

while ( <DATA> ) {
   s/\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\n)/\n -9 \"Missing\"/g;
   print;
}

__DATA__
VALUE LABELS V10
-1
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
-50.00
-33.33
 -10 "Don't Know".
```

Your 'push' line:

```
       push my @negname, $label_name;
```

Isn't going to be doing much though - probably best to do without that. I would also suggest you set the record separator, because that means you can work record by record.

`$/` set to `''` will work in "paragraph mode" - blank line separated.

Maybe something like this?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %recode; 

local $/ = '';

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ( $label_name ) = m/VALUE LABELS (\S+)/;
   my @recode = m/^\s*(\-[\d\.]+)$/gm;
   $recode{$label_name} = \@recode;

   s/\n(-\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\n)/\n -9 \"Missing\"/g;
   print;
}

print "\n\n";

foreach my $key ( sort keys %recode ) {
   foreach my $value ( @{$recode{$key}} ) {
     print "RECODE $key ( $value = -9 )\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
VALUE LABELS V10
-1
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
-50.00
-33.33
 -10 "Don't Know".
```

This gives output of:

```
VALUE LABELS V10
 -9 "Missing"
 1 "Yes".

VALUE LABELS V11
 -9 "Missing"
 -9 "Missing"
 -10 "Don't Know".

RECODE V10 ( -1 = -9 )
RECODE V11 ( -50.00 = -9 )
RECODE V11 ( -33.33 = -9 )
```

Comment: Yep. Edited it again, now I've got your desired output. Hopefully that does the trick?

Comment: I was having some trouble with this for a minute since I had to adapt this to meet my syntax posted above (since this is a small portion of a larger script), which meant keeping the surrounding foreach loop instead of a while loop. I was stuck for a bit, but eventually I changed my if statement to a foreach statement and it worked perfectly. For future reference, does that mean I can't match/capture the same string multiple times in a line within the same if statement? That I need to use a foreach or while for 'plural' operations?